# Query Firestore For Items To Be Displayed using RecyclerView in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, nestedrecyclerview

I have a list of math topics as documents in firebaseFirestore. The objects of these topics (documents) have a field called, rootTopic that can be used to categorize them into groups.

[image]

I would like to query the collection of these topics (documents) and display them in groups using a recyclerView-in-recyclerView as seen below

[image]

THE CHALLENGE IS:

I am not quite sure how best to dynamically query and group these topics(documents). Please assist with hints or snippets on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to query the data you want:

1. Make a query of the whole collection and group the results by the **rootTopic** field. Note that you'll need to partition the returned data, the data will just be ordered.

```
db.collection("Mathematics").orderBy("topicName")
// Then partition the results and render them.
```

2. Somehow get the list of different **topicRoot** and make a query for each of them by applying an equality filter. Here no need for partitioning code wise but several queries would be needed.

In any case I would suggest reading the documentation on [queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and [sorting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) cause it's pretty well explained there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use multiple view types in a single recyclerView instead of multiple recyclerView. [Here is](https://blog.mindorks.com/recyclerview-multiple-view-types-in-android) one example article about it.

Comment: Thanks, @Mustafa, but what I need is simply a way to query firestore and group the received data in recyclerView using the rootTopic as stated in the problem